# Can we say $(\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}n)^2=(\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

Can we say $$(\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}n)^2=(\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2)$$

It works fine if things are finite, does it hold in $n$ goes to infinity?

Comment: Yes. That works.

Comment: Both of these diverge to $\infty$.  So if your number system includes $\infty$, maybe you would say they are equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that (but you probably mean $x_n$ instead of $n$ in the product). A bit more formal argument goes as follows: For any sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of real numbers, define $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n\equiv \lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\prod_{n=1}^N x_n\right)$$ whenever the limit on the right-hand side exists. Now suppose that this limit does exists. Then, since the function $x\mapsto x^2$ is continuous, one has that $$\left(\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n\right)^2=\left\{\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\prod_{n=1}^N x_n\right)\right\}^2=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left\{\left(\prod_{n=1}^N x_n\right)^2\right\}=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\prod_{n=1}^N x_n^2\right)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n^2.$$ The penultimate equality follows from the analogous formula for finite products.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is the continuity necessary? Isn't it sufficient that the mapping be one-to-one?

Comment: @wltrup If a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous and $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb R$ converging to $x\in X$, then it can be shown that
\begin{align*}
\text{(1)}&\,\text{ $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)$ exists; and}\\
\text{(2)}&\,\text{ $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)=f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\right)=f(x)$.}
\end{align*}
I used this convenient property afforded by continuity for $f(t)\equiv t^2$.

Comment: @wltrup Injectivity is not sufficient. For example, consider the function $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$
\begin{align*}
f(x)=\begin{cases}1/x&\text{if $x>0$;}\\0&\text{if $x=0$.}\end{cases}
\end{align*} Also, consider the sequence $$(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)=(1,1/2,1/3,\ldots).$$ Then, $f$ is one-to-one and $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$, but the sequence $$(f(x_1),f(x_2),f(x_3),\ldots)=(1,2,3,\ldots)$$ does not converge, because $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying it for me. Physicist here so, you know, not always aware of the finer details. :)